# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have been able to save my image path into my field in database. The image also appears in my folder in my project. But when i try to call the image, i get this error

> > htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Researching on this error means, there's no image or could be a wrong path. 
I copied the path on my path from the database and tried to find the image from `Finder (on Mac)`, i was able to reach the image using the same path in my field.

How could this be happening please?

PS:  First time user on stack overflow

```
public function updateUserImage(Request $request,$id)
{
    $shop_cart = Cart::findorfail($id);
    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {         
        $image_name = $request->file('image')->hashName();           
        $original_path =  $request->file('image')->move(public_path('/user/auth'),$image_name);
        $shop_cart->saveCart($request);
        $shop_cart->images()->create(['original_path' => $orignal_path]);

        }           
    }       
}
```

**HTML**

```
@foreach($purchased_items as $shop_cart)
@foreach($shop_cart->images as $cart)
<a><img src="{{$cart->orignal_path}}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to echo `File` object instance:

```
{{ $cart->orignal_path }}
```

You can only echo strings.

Comment: how to do get the image from "echoing" strings? new to this

Comment: Call to undefined method \tutorial\Image\LocalFile::getPathname()

Comment: i have been trying to find `LocalFile` can't seem to get what it is actually

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, there's a many to one relationship between `cart` and `images`, so I think you would need to loop through them:

```
@foreach($purchased_items as $shop_cart)
    @foreach($shop_cart as $cart)
        @foreach($cart->images as $image)
            <a><img src="{{$image->orignal_path}}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Or if it's only a one-to-one, then something like this:

```
@foreach($purchased_items as $shop_cart)
    @foreach($shop_cart as $cart)
        <a><img src="{{$cart->images->orignal_path}}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I actually have that already in my code... it was a typo not to show that.. Thanks anyway but that isn't the cause of the error at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple issue. 
{{$cart->original_path}} is returning an error. How find out what object is returning and how to solve it

Go to blade and type this code

```
{{dd($cart->original_path)}} or
{{dd($cart)}}
```

This will show object in your blade, check what it is returning and access it properly and hence your issue will be solved